# How to retrieve more than 5000 items form list using REST API?

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, threshold

I am using $top 5000 in URL of ajax call. Then I am getting data but if I put filters its shows **threshold limit error**.

Comment: Refer this link. This will work for you - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/217254/rest-to-read-more-than-5000-items-from-document-library/217451#217451

Answer (score 1):

The clear cut answer to your question is

> No, you cannot fetch more than 5000 record in one single REST Call
>
> If you want to get data by filtering then also make sure that the filter should not return more than 5000 records.

Also the column you are using for filtering must have Indexing enabled.

For more detail on indexing the column you can look the answers [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/214796/30145).

If you want to know more about indexing columns in detail then there is very fine answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/214797/30145).

Or else you need to write some recursive calls to get the values which will result in multiple REST calls.