# SharePoint 2013 List Threshold Issue

Tags: list, error

I am not able to retrieve list items due to it has crossed threshold limit.
The number of items in the list is 150000 and I am trying to fetch certain items filtered by a field value(say 'pincode'). Such matched values are not more than 20;
Still, I am getting error of 'Threshold limit'

Please check my steps and let me know if I have done anything wrong.

1. Created SP List.
2. Created columns   One of the columns is 'pincode',
3. which I create as Index column (primary index).
4. upload excel list
    data into sharepoint list using powershell.(around 150000 entries)
5. The written code in javascript to fetch List data filtered by
   'pincode' with a particular number (say 110015).

Here is my CAML Query

```
<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='pincode' /><Value Type='Number'>110015</Value> </Eq></Where></Query>
```

Error after operation failed:

> "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds list view threshold enforced by the administrator"

It would highly appreciable if someone could give a solution.

Comment: I had the same problem. Got the solution here
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/214795/when-sharepoint-list-with-5000-items-queried-with-id-returns-expected-result-bu

Comment: Does the error come up when you just open the list or when you start filtering the list?

Comment: @dns_nx As I mentioned in my question I did all those steps provided there, still, I am getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set a limit in your fetched data.

```
<View>
 <Query>      
     YOUR QUERY
 </Query>
  <ViewFields>
        <FieldRef Name='pincode'/>
   </ViewFields>
   <RowLimit>10</RowLimit>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to central admin and increase threshold:

1. Choose your web application and click on ribbon drop down in general settings
2. Choose Resource Throttling.
3. Increase List View Threshold param

Comment: If number of items are somewhere around threshold limit (say 6000-7000) then it is fine although it is not recommended. But number here is 1.5 lacs. There must be some other solution.

Comment: Ok, try to use row limit or content iterator